# Add text to input using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I would like that jquery adds the value of a **class="num"** to the form with the **id="form2"** when the **class="text"** is clicked. Its important that only the value of the next **"num"-class**  after the **"text"**-class is added to the form!

```
<p class="text" >
<a class="num"><%= g.nummer %></a><a class="bez"><%= g.bezeichnung %></a>
</p>

<input id="form2" name="suche" type="text">
```

My actual code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".text", function() {
   $("#Content").html($(this).next(".text1").html());
   $("#form2").html($(this).next(".num").val());
   $('.text').css('color','');
   $(this).css( "color", "red" );
  });
 });
```

But somehow this line wont work:

```
$("#form2").html($(this).next(".num").val());
```

Thanks!

Comment: change `.html()` to `.val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.num` is a child of `.text`, rather than next element.

Change:

```
$("#form2").html($(this).next(".num").val());
```

To:

```
$("#form2").val($(this).children(".num").html());
```

and as correctly said in comments: use `val()` to get/set value of `input` element, and `.html()` to get/set contents of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var yourVal = "someText";

$("#form2").children(".num").val(yourVal);
```